# Packaging for Launchpad PPA

Tags: ubuntu, packaging, debian-based

I want to start with what I have and end up with what I need.

I have:

- a folder with some files
- a post install bash script that will do some wonders in the system (bash command, completion, etc)

I need:

- copy my directory to specified location
- execute my post install bash script
- create a package for Launchpad ppa so I can easily add my repository and install my package that will resolve my dependencies through aptitute and do all above

What I did:

- mostly nothing useful

  - created a simple deb package that I can install though dpkg -i package.deb (doesn't resolve my dependencies, just check if are installed)
  - followed a very big tutorial (the only one I found http://goo.gl/M7eIv):
  - added GPG keys and installed all the dependencies but I'm lost at the part where I have to create the actual package.

Can someone offer me a good tutorial that google doesn't consider it relevant to me or point me in the right direction ? I also want to mention that I have some basic-intermediary linux skill (I don't really know how to autoevaluate me)

Answer (score 2):

After eight hours of not sleeping, three redbulls and one coffee I found this and it did worked: https://www.ebower.com/docs/ubuntu-ppa/